# How to receive confirmation in Volley or Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-volley, retrofit

I want to post some data to a MySQL database. The server-side code will determine whether the data is valid and respond with that determination. Upon receiving this response, the application-side code must decide if it needs to try again or continue on. I have tried callbacks, RequestFuture, and spin-waiting, but it is starting to seem like this type of functionality is not possible with Volley (making decisions based on the server response). Has anyone else had success in implementing this type of functionality?

Main Thread

```
postCampaign(campaign);
if (//data was invalid) {
    //do postCampaign(campaign) again
}
```

Main Thread

```
private void postCampaign(final Campaign campaign) {
    campaign.setRoomCode("XXXXXXXX");
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // I want to make a decision based on response
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    ...
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            // put data
            return params;
        }
    };
    NetworkController.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from server side, you need to grab the data send by your app. Then you need to check for validations like is the passed data empty/incorrect(incase of passwords check for it against the password in database if its the correct one or not).

In the server side validation of your data, if the data is successfully validated and updated in database then give a *`success response`* with proper *`response code`* or else if database updation is failed, then give an *`error response`* with proper *`error response`* code. You may pass these response as a json format to the client(or in whatever format you are comfortable parsing)

Now in the app side you may have a response callback method(available in `retrofit/volley`). From the response obtained in this callback check if it is a success response or failure response and make **appropriate decisions** for success/ failure cases